# Installing drivers for windows?

Tags: unity

I am buing **assamble self** PC for playing games. 
I am wondering, all the drivers, which are most likely for Windows, can i just use them on Ubuntu?

So if i understand you right, it will automaticaly detect the drivers, no need for installs ? or it find custom drivers for ubuntu.

This is the setup, will there be any problem with it?

[image]

Comment: Graphics drivers always are unreliable. You'll need to install graphics drivers (which Ubuntu will detect, but not install automatically). I'd recommend that you research support for that specific card.

Comment: If you want to run Steam under linux, an Nvidia card is a must. Green cards do much better 3d in Linux than red, because while nvidia drivers are bad, the ati's fglrx is a bug incarnate. And Steam team surely tests their work much more on nvidia.

Comment: Oh, and all HDD tests I have seen put seagate on the bottom of the list. Select one of Hitachi or Samsung. Definitely get a separate SSD for OS. For linux, even a 32GB one would be enough.

Comment: Hmm, maybe i should just go with Windows then. You get more for you money with AMD.

Didnt know Ubuntu would be so advanced.

Comment: Think of that: you can save that extra expence on not needing to pay for antivirus. ;)

Answer (score 3):

No. Drivers for Windows are for Windows. Ubuntu comes pre-loaded with almost all the drivers you will need. In some cases, there may not be drivers available for a particular piece of hardware. If you are using an Nvidia or ATI video card, you may need to install the proprietary drivers to get full utilization of the hardware, but the open source drivers that are  already installed should work well enough to get you that far.

Answer (score 0):

Yes bro you can at least use Wireless Drivers made for Windows using ndiswrapper or ndisgtk or Windows Wireless Drivers tool which can be found in Ubuntu Software Centre.

Comment: at least and at most. This answer encompasses select examples of network hardware. If something is not said to work with linux, a beginner user should not hope to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the drivers will be installed and autocratically detected by Ubuntu, for some closed source drivers (like nvidia drivers) you can add them using the "Additional drivers" option after installing Ubuntu.

The only drivers you might need from windows (if not supported by Ubuntu will be for the wireless card (if you have one) in whitch you can use `wrappers`

other windows drivers can not be installed on Ubunut/Linux.