# How can I install a Windows monitor driver [DELL E1910H] on Ubuntu?

Tags: drivers, dell

I have an old computer that ran on windows vista, and after finding it in my basement, I decided to put it on Windows 10, but it couldn't handle Windows 10, so I switched it to Ubuntu yesterday since I have experience with it.

The problem I have is the monitor I have is 1. old and doesn't have windows 10 drivers, and 2. The drivers are running on .exe, which Linux doesn't seem to recognize, even on the system and updates application. Is there any way I can run these drivers on Ubuntu? I can't stand this aspect ratio.

This is the driver: https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-ca/product-support/product/dell-e1910h/drivers

```
xrandr
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1024 x 768, current 1024 x 768, maximum 1024 x 768
default connected primary 1024x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm
1024x768      76.00* 
1366x768_60.00 (0x3b8) 85.250MHz -HSync +VSync
    h: width  1368 start 1440 end 1576 total 1784 skew    0 clock  
47.79KHz
    v: height  768 start  771 end  781 total  798           clock  
59.88Hz
1368x768_60.00 (0x3be) 85.250MHz -HSync +VSync
    h: width  1368 start 1440 end 1576 total 1784 skew    0 clock  
47.79KHz
    v: height  768 start  771 end  781 total  798           clock  
59.88Hz
```

Comment: Why are you thinking you need a monitor driver? Does monitor work?

Comment: Which Ubuntu version are you using?

Comment: @Pilot6 it works but its aspect ratio is not normal

Comment: @Pilot6 I am using the most recent LTS version, so 20.04 I believe

Comment: You can't use Windows drivers anyway. In most cases problems with resolution are caused by a bad VGA to HDMI adapter, it can be fixed by replacing the adapter or setting resolution manually. Please add output of `xrandr` command to your question.

Comment: @Pilot6 It can't be from the VGA port because there is no adapter, and when it was on Windows Vista it was running fine

Comment: It is normal that Windows works better with bad adapters, especially when you install a monitor "driver". It is not a really a driver but a resolution setting, that can't be detected through a pad adapter.

Comment: I asked to post output of `xrandr` command, not the word `xrandr` that is obviously useless.

Comment: @Pilot6 yeah sorry Im just stupid

Comment: So you have two options: to get a better adapter, or set a resolution manually. To set it manully you need to know what is the optimal resolution for your monitor and set it this way: https://askubuntu.com/questions/377937/how-do-i-set-a-custom-resolution

Comment: @Pilot6 thank you, I will try both.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing drivers for windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/533306/installing-drivers-for-windows)